# Get-WebConfiguration returns no result

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to read some attributes from the web.config file via the `Get-WebConfiguration` commandlet with powershell.

I've already tested the command with

```
Get-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'iis:\sites\default test web site\referenz_ad' -filter "connectionStrings/add[@name='ApplicationDatabase']"
```

which returns the following as expected:

```
connectionString      : server=...;uid=...;pwd=...;database=...;language=english
name                  : ApplicationDatabase
providerName          : System.Data.SqlClient
PSPath                : MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Test Web Site/Referenz_AD
Location              : 
ConfigurationPathType : Location
ItemXPath             : /connectionStrings/add[@name='ApplicationDatabase']
Attributes            : {connectionString, name, providerName}
ChildElements         : {}
ElementTagName        : add
Methods               : 
Schema                : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

If I want to read a different Node attribute with

```
Get-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'iis:\sites\default test web site\referenz_ad' -filter "configSections/section[@name='dotless']"
```

I get an empty result (nothing is shown at all) but also no error message. The path is correctly written - copy/paste to eliminate misspellings. I've also tried different paths. Some do return values most not...

Here is an example of the web.config file with nodes that return no results:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler,dotless.Core" />
    <section name="storageConfig" type="Cubido.DMS.Storage.Common.Configuration.StorageConfigSection" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..." requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..." requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..." requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
.
.
.
</configuration>
```

Does someone have an idea why the second command returns no result?

Greetings
Alex

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Get-WebConfiguration` (and the official [help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/get-webconfiguration?view=winserver2012-ps) is unhelpful), but - generally speaking - if a `-Filter` argument matches nothing, it is normal for the command to quietly return nothing. The argument looks like an XPath query - perhaps that query doesn't find what you expect it to find.

Comment: Is it possible that the IIS does not read all information from the web.config file? I've now tried to find the information on the IIS but can't find it there either. That would explain why the `Get-WebConfiguration` cant find it...

Answer (score 0):

dotless is your HTTP handler.it means you are trying to get the value of the HTTP handler.

for that you could try to use below command:

```
Get-WebHandler -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site'
```

this command returns all IIS request handlers.

if you want to get specif handler detail you could use parameter like a name.

```
Get-WebHandler -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -name "StaticFile"
```

for more detail you could refer this link:

[Get-WebHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/get-webhandler?view=winserver2012-ps)

Comment: The filter with dotless was just ment as an example. I have the problem also with other filters that do not show a result, although it exists.

Comment: @scarabeaus could you share some examples?

Comment: @scarabeaus The only way to achieve this is to read the config directly by using an XML library.